# How can I integrate paho eclipse library in Qt

Tags: qt, paho

I want to know if there is a way to integrate eclipse paho library with qt

Right now I am manually including all the c and h files in my project.
Which now causes a segmentation fault for memcpy

I want to know is there a better way to integrate paho eclipse with qt?

```
Thread 1 "AwsIot" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
memcpy () at ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S:608
608 ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  memcpy () at ../sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S:608
#1  0x00409540 in writeMQTTString (pptr=pptr@entry=0x7effc4bc, mqttstring=...) at ../AwsIot/mqtt/MQTTPacket.c:198
#2  0x00409798 in MQTTSerialize_publish (buf=buf@entry=0x48c8d8 "0\"\217\320", buflen=buflen@entry=10340, dup=<optimized out>, qos=0, retained=retained@entry=0 '\000', packetid=2468, topicName=..., 
    payload=0x50c9c8 "{\"hello\":\"from qt\"}", payloadlen=19) at ../AwsIot/mqtt/MQTTSerializePublish.c:78
#3  0x00407f0c in MqttClient::sendMqPub_onEntry (this=0x48c8c0) at ../AwsIot/mqttclient.cpp:244
#4  0x0040a57c in MqttClient::qt_static_metacall (_o=0x48c8c0, _c=<optimized out>, _id=<optimized out>, _a=<optimized out>) at moc_mqttclient.cpp:296
#5  0x7620350e in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x7626fb26 in QAbstractState::entered(QAbstractState::QPrivateSignal) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x7626fc60 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x76268a58 in QStateMachinePrivate::enterStates(QEvent*, QList<QAbstractState*> const&, QList<QAbstractState*> const&, QSet<QAbstractState*> const&, QHash<QAbstractState*, QVector<QPropertyAssignment> >&, QList<QAbstractAnimation*> const&) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x76269468 in QStateMachinePrivate::microstep(QEvent*, QList<QAbstractTransition*> const&, CalculationCache*) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x76269670 in QStateMachinePrivate::_q_process() () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#11 0x76269d88 in QStateMachinePrivate::handleTransitionSignal(QObject*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#12 0x7626bee2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x7620357e in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00407d1a in MqttClient::publishAnyData (this=this@entry=0x48c8c0, topic=..., payload=..., dup=0, packetId=packetId@entry=2468, qos=qos@entry=0, retain=0) at ../AwsIot/mqttclient.cpp:303
#15 0x0040a1d2 in MqttClient::qt_static_metacall (_o=_o@entry=0x48c8c0, _c=_c@entry=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=_id@entry=41, _a=_a@entry=0x7effca48)
    at /opt/poky/2.7.1/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/QtCore/qrefcount.h:60
#16 0x0040aabe in MqttClient::qt_metacall (this=0x48c8c0, _c=QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, _id=41, _a=0x7effca48) at moc_mqttclient.cpp:499
#17 0x767d258c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Edit 1:

I have attached my .pro file here

```
QT += qml quick gui svg xml xmlpatterns network
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mqttclient.cpp \
    mqtt/MQTTConnectClient.c \
    mqtt/MQTTConnectServer.c \
    mqtt/MQTTDeserializePublish.c \
    mqtt/MQTTFormat.c \
    mqtt/MQTTPacket.c \
    mqtt/MQTTSerializePublish.c \
    mqtt/MQTTSubscribeClient.c \
    mqtt/MQTTSubscribeServer.c \
    mqtt/MQTTUnsubscribeClient.c \
    mqtt/MQTTUnsubscribeServer.c \
    statemachine/guardedsignaltransition.cpp \
    statemachine/p4statemachine.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    mqttclient.h \
    mqtt/MQTTConnect.h \
    mqtt/MQTTFormat.h \
    mqtt/MQTTPacket.h \
    mqtt/MQTTPublish.h \
    mqtt/MQTTSubscribe.h \
    mqtt/MQTTUnsubscribe.h \
    mqtt/StackTrace.h \
    statemachine/custom_global_var.h \
    statemachine/guardedsignaltransition.h \
    statemachine/p4statemachine.h \
    statemachine/qt_state_machine_macros.h
```

And this is function that is apparently causing the problem
So Once I click publish data on qml

the call goes to mqttclient.cpp

```
void MqttClient:: sendMqPub_onEntry(){
    qDebug()<<"sendMqPub_onEntry";
    if (txqueue->isEmpty())
    {
        txqueue->clear();
        emit nothingToPub();
    }
    else
    {
        if (gTxPublishInfo != static_cast<_S_MQTT_PUBLISH_INFO *>(nullptr)) {
            delete gTxPublishInfo->bap;
            delete gTxPublishInfo->tap;
            delete gTxPublishInfo;
            gTxPublishInfo = (_S_MQTT_PUBLISH_INFO *)nullptr;
        }
        gTxPublishInfo = txqueue->dequeue();
        memset(gMqttTxBuff,0,MQTT_TX_BUFF_LEN_MAX);
        int len = MQTTSerialize_publish(gMqttTxBuff, sizeof(gMqttTxBuff), gTxPublishInfo->dup,gTxPublishInfo->qos, gTxPublishInfo->retain, gTxPublishInfo->packetId, gTxPublishInfo->topic, (unsigned char *)gTxPublishInfo->payload, gTxPublishInfo->payloadLen);
        m_mqttSkt->write(QByteArray((const char*)gMqttTxBuff,len));
    }
}
```

Which then goes to MQTTSerializePublish.c

```
int MQTTSerialize_publish(unsigned char* buf, int buflen, unsigned char dup, int qos, unsigned char retained, unsigned short packetid,
        MQTTString topicName, unsigned char* payload, int payloadlen)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = buf;
    MQTTHeader header = {0};
    int rem_len = 0;
    int rc = 0;

    FUNC_ENTRY;
    if (MQTTPacket_len(rem_len = MQTTSerialize_publishLength(qos, topicName, payloadlen)) > buflen)
    {
        rc = MQTTPACKET_BUFFER_TOO_SHORT;
        goto exit;
    }

    header.bits.type = PUBLISH;
    header.bits.dup = dup;
    header.bits.qos = qos;
    header.bits.retain = retained;
    writeChar(&ptr, header.byte); /* write header */

    ptr += MQTTPacket_encode(ptr, rem_len); /* write remaining length */;

    writeMQTTString(&ptr, topicName);

    if (qos > 0)
        writeInt(&ptr, packetid);

    memcpy(ptr, payload, payloadlen);
    ptr += payloadlen;

    rc = ptr - buf;

exit:
    FUNC_EXIT_RC(rc);
    return rc;
}
```

Which finally goes to MQTTPacket.c and crashes

```
void writeMQTTString(unsigned char** pptr, MQTTString mqttstring)
{
    if (mqttstring.lenstring.len > 0)
    {
        writeInt(pptr, mqttstring.lenstring.len);
        memcpy(*pptr, mqttstring.lenstring.data, mqttstring.lenstring.len);
        *pptr += mqttstring.lenstring.len;
    }
    else if (mqttstring.cstring)
        writeCString(pptr, mqttstring.cstring);
    else
        writeInt(pptr, 0);
}
```

Comment: I have added my contents of my .pro file along with the function that is causing me the problem

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1) Are you using paho.mqtt.c or paho.mqtt.cpp? 2) Have you compiled the paho.mqtt.X project or just downloaded it? Considering the above I recommend using X since it is made for C++ and if you have only downloaded it then you should compile it.

Comment: I am using paho.mqtt.c and then I am using it in QT. Do I need to compile paho.mqtt separately or QT should do it?

Comment: As I indicated, it is better that you use paho.mqtt.cpp and it is better that you compile it separately since it has a CMakeLists ready to compile it and then it will be easier to add it to the .pro, use the manual https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp#unix-and-linux to do it

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, if this sound like a stupid question. But If I compile it then I could use it as a module just like any-other module in qt right? Or Is my understanding totally wrong?

Comment: Not as a Qt module but as an external library, it seems that you don't know the C++ compilation process, I recommend you read about it so that you understand.

Answer (score 0):

My application did not crash on valgrind but it did on gdb and that led me to investigate.
Apparently the length variable was not initialized. Which was the root cause. As soon as I set it to zero. It started working and I am happy now.

What I also found out was that the raspberry-pi is a very unforgiving environment.